# pick image from gallery ,convert in to base 64 and upload to rest API

Tags: api, kotlin, base64, uri, gallery

I have an API which accepts base64 images

I'm following this approach to pick image from gallery, convert it to base64 and upload it to API, when I check the base64 output in decode websites, it seems fine, but my API doesn't accept that
then I think maybe the problem is about API, so I converted an image with the help of some websites, and retry the same request in postman, and boom! image was uploaded successfully
so where is the issue?

**here is the result from gallery**

```
private val galleryLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val resultCode = result.resultCode
        val data = result.data
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                showProgressBar()
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    currentImageUri = data?.data
                    binding.ivPoster.load(data?.data)
                    val bitmap = convertUriToBitmap(data?.data!!)
                    path= convertBitmapTOBase64(bitmap)
                    dismissProgressBar()
                }
        }  else {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Task Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
    }
```

**here is the functions that I use to convert token uri from gallery and convert it to base64**

```
private fun convertUriToBitmap(uri:Uri):Bitmap{
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireContext().contentResolver, uri)
    } else {
        val source=ImageDecoder.createSource(requireContext().contentResolver, uri)
        ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
    }
}

private fun convertBitmapTOBase64(bitmap:Bitmap):String{
    val stream= ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,stream)
    val image= stream.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(image,Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

**updated**

here is the network request:

```
@POST("api/v1/movies")
suspend fun pushMovies(@Body movie:UploadMovieModel): Response<UploadMovieModel>
```

and here is base64 code generated by code:
[generated base64](https://gist.github.com/farshad049/8a863bff671d85b5cbd5d0da653eefa0)

Comment: Can you please add an example of a base64 string that was created with your code?

Comment: Have you logged your base64 ? Are you getting base64 value? Then when error you are getting from api when you are doing with network call. You might also have chance to miss something in api call. Could you please update you api call code?

Comment: I really appreciate you guys for answering me, I just updated the post